# How to delete User with User ID and GID 0

Tags: 14.04, bash, passwd

I just created a user with UID and GID to 0. Now when I access this user lets say "**abc**" will login as root. But when I loin as root i cannot list all the directories with ls command where i can do it with the user abc.

I want to go back to normal, delete this user with uid and gid o. I tried to update the passwd file but it does not let me change it.

How do i delete this user abc and use only root as root

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of deleting the user you can change the UID and the GID of your user:

```
usermod -u <NEWUID> <USERNAME>    
groupmod -g <NEWGID> <GROUP>
```

The default group has same name of your username.

Remember in Ubuntu the UId from 0 to 99 is reserved as system users.

Also users with UID < 1000 will not appear in the user lists so choose a UID > 1000

Now you can delete the user eaily and safely if you want to.

Comment: How do I know which group.

Comment: The group is by default same as your username

Comment: OK thats now done. I successfully deleted the user "abc"  now i cannot list the documents and files using ls.. like before i could ls and it used to list folders like picture, etc, var and all. Now it only shows up folder name find

Comment: what directories are talking about? Is those created by the deleted user before?

Comment: No the system folders, like the folders in file system. Like var, urs, sys, lib

Comment: what is the user you are using?

Comment: I am using root , since i created and deleted new user with UID 0, and when I use ls from root it displays one folder called find. In which case i used to get a list of folders and when did ls to the new user abc

Comment: what is the output of `whoami` command

Comment: whoami = root,  the folder inside root directory in file system has one folder called find..  however when i do ls with new user abc with UIO 0 it gives me list of folders like var, etc, opt, run, media and so on which i guess is the main system file

Comment: you told me you delete user abc? is that right?

Comment: yes, i deleted the user abc, but when i had user abc and when i did ls to the user abc it gave me list of system file folders like above . which I cannot do with root i mean which does not show any folder with root .

Comment: output of command `getent group root`

Comment: getent group root  gives root:x:0:

Comment: do you have another user with `sudo`?

Comment: yes i do have ..

Comment: you can list filesystems using that user?

Comment: using root from your terminal. output of `ls /`

Comment: i get folder called find.. Actually i had a look in root folder in the file system. there i saw this file . In actual the root doesnot show me the main file system folders , it shows me whats inside the folder root which is. The root folder is in file system alongside var, etc and so on

Comment: Please note that the folder `root` is  not the same as `/` so please tell me the output of the command `ls /`

Comment: Thank you it solved. the ls / output shows everything now.. Thanks a lot.. Thanks for your time . i found what happened here.

Comment: @DeepeshThapa ok thats good.